# Mysql deadlock explanation

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I need some help solving a deadlock situation I am facing.

The below is a test script I have that simulates the issue I am having
I have a tags table which, per request, might insert/update a lot of entries, all in one transaction.

I know that the deadlock happens because a lot of threads lock the same entries and I would like some feedback as to how I can avoid them

I am running ab -n 100 -c 5 http://localhost/script.php

This the table

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` 
(
  `id` INT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `weight` INT(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` ENUM('1','2','3') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tag_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

<?php
function go() {

    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $db->start_transaction();
    $tgs = array('electricity', 'emergency', 'trees', 'New Jersey', 'Canada funnelled');
    foreach($tgs as $tg) {
        $arr_tags = array(
            'name' => $tg,
            'weight' => '0',
            'type' => TagTable::PRIMARY
        );
        $tag_instance = new Tag($arr_tags);
        $tag_instance->save(true);
        // the save method executes a query like the below
        // INSERT INTO tags (weight, type, modified, id, name) VALUES(0, "1", NULL, NULL, "$tag") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight+1;

    }
    $db->commit();
}
go();
?>
```

Comment: Can you share the output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS. This will output the the latest detected deadlock. That will help debug better.

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, even with InnoDB deadlocks can occur. The reason for this?

The [clustered index (known internally as the gen_clust_index)](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554) can be intermittently locked in the middle of a transaction involving bulk INSERTs. What is interesting about INSERTs in transactions has a lot to do with the InnoDB log files. The previous state of a row of data you INSERT is one of a nonexistent row. Such [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) data representing a nonexistent row would be recorded in the redo logs to support rollbacks, dirty reads, and things like these. Doing bulk INSERTs will create a lot of these nonexistent rows for rollback.

I once went through a series of questions from one person in the DBA StackExchange about deadlock situations with consecutive UPDATEs. Here are those questions and my answers:

- [Will these two queries result in a deadlock if executed in sequence?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/will-these-two-queries-result-in-a-deadlock-if-executed-in-sequence/3224#3224)
- [Trouble deciphering a deadlock in an innodb status log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3179/trouble-deciphering-a-deadlock-in-an-innodb-status-log/3185#3185)
- [Reasons for occasionally slow queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3302/reasons-for-occasionally-slow-queries/3305#3305)

You may have to try executing the bulk INSERTs without a transaction with either of the following:

- with a COMMIT after each INSERT
- use AUTOCOMMIT=1

If you must have the INSERTs in a transaction, try increasing the size of the InnoDB Log Files and the [bulk insert buffer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size):

Step 01) Add this line to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
bulk_insert_buffer_size=256M
innodb_log_file_size=2047M
```

Step 02) `service mysql stop`

Step 03) `rm -f /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile[01]`

Step 04) `service mysql start`

During the startup of mysql, ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 are recreated

Give it a Try !!! I hope it helps.

UPDATE 2011-10-31 12:43 EDT

[I just answered a question like this in the DBA StackExchange 3 days ago](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7363/concurrently-update-with-limit-mysql/7370#7370)

Comment: HI and thanks for your help. I tried what you mention but I still get a lot of deadlocks. I handle them in my app logic but even so I end up with a lot of them being aborted. I just tried a ab -n 800 -c 50 and only half of them succeeded (imagine if I did not handle the deadlocks in my app). It's really frustrating. I know that if I commit more often, I will not have this problem, but then the whole point of the transaction is to succeed or fail as a whole